# Google Analytics track UTM link

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have pages A and B.
I have 10 UTM traceable link for assessment from 1 to 10, which lead to two thank you pages.

How can I see in Analytics reverse link path:
e.g.
Thankyou1 -> Links from UTM -> and from which page A or B are the clicks.

something like this:

from page A -> are clicked links 1,2,5,9 -> and went on Thankyou1
from page B -> are clicked links 2,7 -> and went on Thankyou2

In Analytics I see only the Source / Medium which helps me for UTM tracking, but I can not pull the page where links are clicked.

How to see the flow from the article -> in one of the 10 links -> to one of the two thanks pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a destination goal in google analytics and set your thank you pages as goal completion URLs
After you've completed goals you can view your goal data in
Conversion >> Goals

There you will have 4 Reports that will help you see your required data
http://take.ms/ZOct0

Here is a link that will help you understand Goals and Goal reports.
https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2392060/back-to-basics-goal-reports-in-google-analytics

You can also create a custom report using dimension
Goal completion URL with source / medium and Goal previous step 1,2 and 3